# Docker + Selenium Grid: Is it possible to do true cross-platform testing?

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid

I am new to Docker and I am exploring Docker as a way to build a more stable and maintainable Selenium GRID. I have completed the Docker + Selenium Grid course at Udemy, but I still don't know a few things.

My company has a web portal and I am required to verify functionality across browers and OSes:

- Recent versions of Chrome on recent versions of Mac, Linux & Windows
- Recent versions of Firefox on recent versions of Mac, Linus & Windows
- Recent versions of Safari on Mac
- Recent versions of IE and Edge on recent versions of Windows

As far as I can tell a Docker container is 'linux-like'. Does that mean it serves only to verify Chrome and Firefox on linux. Is there some way to use Docker to verify these other browser + OS combos?

Comment: I recommend looking into Docker for Windows. 
You should be able to build Linux container and Windows container and run them on a Windows machine. Not sure what the status is for Mac.
The following article may be helpful [Run Linux and Windows Containers on Windows 10](https://stefanscherer.github.io/run-linux-and-windows-containers-on-windows-10/)

Comment: I have updated the answer for dockerizing IE/EDGE, based on my findings. Check if that solution works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47865355/5449500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explore the below projects for selenium grid with docker on Linux and Windows .

1)https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/blob/master/README.md

2)https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

3)https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/blob/master/docs/usage_examples.md

Recent versions of Safari on Mac 
-: I am not sure about the safari availability in docker hub , but try putting your question for mac in docker-for-selenium project they will help you .

Recent versions of IE and Edge on recent versions of Windows 
-:Yes , their are some challenges while implementing the IE and Edge in windows containers.

please check this thread @https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/214

it is clearly mentioned here , "**Windows feature enabling to install the GUI within a windows container**" ,So challenges are their to enable GUI for windows container .

But still if you want to go for cross browser testing 
with other options available for windows . you can try exploring this @ https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

***UPDATES***

***Copying my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55704955/5449500***

Still there is no official approach to run IE/EDGE inside docker as
**"[No Windows docker images have GUI, so we cannot test IE11, EDGE.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/214)"**

But,We can install virtual-box and make this happen.

***This approach adds extra layer of virtualization[Nesting of virtualization] on the top of docker to make the IE/Edge execution happen and I think in near future it may leads to to performance issue for heavy testing.***

If Selenium testing is what you are looking for and don't have heavy load , you can give a try to the approach mentioned in the link.

[Youtube - Selenium Windows containers in Docker under Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJCvvfSE2FE)

[Github - Windows Images](https://github.com/aerokube/windows-images)

[Blogpost - selenium-on-windows-docker-revolution](https://medium.com/@aandryashin/selenium-on-windows-docker-revolution-f5a7eab205ad)

Comment: Very nice level of detail, BTW.