# Selenium hub with internet explorer node

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-grid

Is possible to use selenium hub with internet explorer node?

I can use Selenium hub with Firefox and Chrome node using docker and kubernetes with the images on https://hub.docker.com/u/selenium. But in Selenium's docker hub don't has internet explorer image. Have another way to do that (using docker and kubernetes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately not. See [Is it possible to dockerize Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338675/is-it-possible-to-dockerize-internet-explorer).  Docker doesn't want to support a browser that does not have a headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

***Copying my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55704955/5449500***

Still there is no official approach to run IE/EDGE inside docker as
**"[No Windows docker images have GUI, so we cannot test IE11, EDGE.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/214)"**

But,We can install virtual-box and make this happen.

***This approach adds extra layer of virtualization[Nesting of virtualization] on the top of docker to make the IE/Edge execution happen and I think in near future it may leads to to performance issue for heavy testing.***

If Selenium testing is what you are looking for and don't have heavy load , you can give a try to the approach mentioned in the link.

[Youtube - Selenium Windows containers in Docker under Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJCvvfSE2FE)

[Github - Windows Images](https://github.com/aerokube/windows-images)

[Blogpost - selenium-on-windows-docker-revolution](https://medium.com/@aandryashin/selenium-on-windows-docker-revolution-f5a7eab205ad)